# How can I load more results on a web page using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, dom, web-scraping

I want to use VBA for load more results in the below link:
http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/

First load of the page shows me only half of the total results, but I want to load all the data from the page.

I think somehow I must click the "Show more matches" link, but I don't know how to do this.

Could anyone help me with any idea?

If I have much more games to load and after the first click on the load more games will still be games hidden, how can I see all the games?

The source code of the link is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadMoreGames(); return false;">Show more matches</a>
```

Below you could find a screen shoot of the link:

[image: Image link]

Comment: Use `getElementsByTagName("a")` to get a collection of all of the links on the page, then loop over that checking the innerText for "Show more matches" - call `click` on the matching element

Comment: One piece of an advice from me: `Do Until InStr(ie.document.getElementById("preload").getAttribute("Style"), "display: none;") <> 0: DoEvents: Loop` The website uses various elements informing about loading status. `IE.ReadyState` or `IE.Busy` usually fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the function name `loadMoreGames()` assigned to `onclick` event in the anchor node `<a href="#" onclick="loadMoreGames(); return false;">Show more matches</a>`, so you may just call that function instead of `click()` and loop to wait until loading completed as @RyszardJędraszyk commented:

```
Sub Test()

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.flashscore.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/"
        Do: DoEvents: Loop While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        Do: DoEvents: Loop While .Document.readyState <> "complete"
        .Document.parentWindow.execScript "loadMoreGames();"
        Do: DoEvents: Loop While .Document.getElementById("preload").Style.display = "none"
    End With

End Sub
```